# rails devise simple authentication token getting 403 forbbiden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using rails 4.2.6 with ruby 2.1.1p76.

I am using devise with phone_number as primary identifier.

I am trying to create API services for login but I am always get 403 error forbidden  .

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  #skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User
  respond_to :json


  def create
    #user = User.find_by phone_number: params['user']['phone_number']
    warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    if(current_user != nil)

        #current_user.authentication_token = generateToken
            render :status => 200,
               :json => {  :code => 200,
                               :data => {:user => current_user} }
    else
        @new_user = User.new(user_params)
        @new_user.email = 'null@null.com'
        if @new_user.save!
            render :status => 201,
                   :json => {  :code => 201,
                               :data => {:user => @new_user} }
        else
            render :status => 500,
                   :json => {  :code => 500,
                               :data => {} }
        end
    end

  end


  def failure
    render :status => 403,
           :json => { :code => 200,
                      :data => {} }
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email,:password,:phone_number)
  end
end
```

the message I send

```
{"user":{"phone_number":"0535934245","authentication_token":"2zfaWT2QySFigyE9XvsP"}}
```

HOPE FOR U R HELP.

BEST REGARDS,
SHARON DAHAN

Answer (score 0):

CURL EXAMPLE FOR THE LOGIN API

curl -v http://xyz/users/sign_in -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user": {"login": "7838712847" ,"password": "8489"}}'

this curl should return the user object having authentication token. Now after login this authentication token user will use to communicate with our application

So After login you need to send the authentication token of user in every request header

Comment: My wish is if the user does not exist to create him and if he exist just login

Comment: Sorry for late response, we have to solve it in conditional way at controller level I did it once and rocks